# Documents and examples of PythonMagick

Tags: python, imagemagick

Where can I find the document and examples of [PythonMagick](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonMagick)?

I did a search on Google but no much information was found.

Comment: Jack can you change the accepted answer on this please?

Comment: jack I know you're busy with Twitter and all but we trying to make this site work please

Answer (score -14, accepted):

EDIT: Nothing to see here. Refer to better answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5188661/503688).

---

It is a bindings to the [MagickWand API](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php) : http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/pythonmagickwand

So you can use all of the MagickWand API functions.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import Magick

 # Use the Python Imaging Library to create a Tk display
 dpy = Magick.TkDisplay(startmain=0)

 # Read the image
 img = Magick.read('test.gif')

 # Display the image
 dpy(img)
 dpy(img.Swirl(90))

 dpy.startmain=1
 dpy.show()
```

Comment: I don't know why this got accepted, it is not correct. There are *two different Python-ImageMagick APIs*. The OP is asking about one (PythonMagick), and you're answering with information about the other (PythonMagickWand).

Comment: Yes my bad, I don't know either.

Answer (score 34):

I could not find them anywhere either but this is how I went about using it anyway.

Example

```
import PythonMagick
image = PythonMagick.Image("sample_image.jpg")
print image.fileName()
print image.magick()
print image.size().width()
print image.size().height()
```

With output like this

```
sample_image.jpg
JPEG
345
229
```

To find out what image methods are available for example I looked in the cpp source. Taking the **Image** object binding: Image implemented in **_Image.cpp** 
Or better still look at the suggestion for getting the methods contained in another answer by [Klaus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740158/documents-and-examples-of-pythonmagick/5532685#5532685)  on this page.

In this file you'll see lines like this

```
    .def("contrast", &Magick::Image::contrast)
    .def("convolve", &Magick::Image::convolve)
    .def("crop", &Magick::Image::crop)
    .def("cycleColormap", &Magick::Image::cycleColormap)
    .def("despeckle", &Magick::Image::despeckle)
```

The bit in quotes maps to the function name of the Image object.  Following this approach you can figure out enough to be useful. For example **Geometry** specific methods are in **_Geometry.cpp** and the include the usual suspects like

```
     .def("width", (size_t (Magick::Geometry::*)() const)&Magick::Geometry::width)
    .def("height", (void (Magick::Geometry::*)(size_t) )&Magick::Geometry::height)
    .def("height", (size_t (Magick::Geometry::*)() const)&Magick::Geometry::height)
    .def("xOff", (void (Magick::Geometry::*)(ssize_t) )&Magick::Geometry::xOff)
    .def("xOff", (ssize_t (Magick::Geometry::*)() const)&Magick::Geometry::xOff)
```

Answer (score 19):

To find out the methods type in Python:

```
import PythonMagick
dir(PythonMagick.Image())
```

Then you get an output like this:

> `['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__instance_size__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'adaptiveThreshold', 'addNoise', 'adjoin', 'affineTransform', 'animationDelay', 'animationIterations', 'annotate', 'antiAlias', 'attribute', 'backgroundColor', 'backgroundTexture', 'baseColumns', 'baseFilename', 'baseRows', 'blur', 'border', 'borderColor', 'boundingBox', 'boxColor', 'cacheThreshold', 'channel', 'channelDepth', 'charcoal', 'chop', 'chromaBluePrimary', 'chromaGreenPrimary', 'chromaRedPrimary', 'chromaWhitePoint', 'classType', 'clipMask', 'colorFuzz', 'colorMap', 'colorMapSize', 'colorSpace', 'colorize', 'columns', 'comment', 'compare', 'compose', 'composite', 'compressType', 'contrast', 'convolve', 'crop', 'cycleColormap', 'debug', 'defineSet', 'defineValue', 'density', 'depth', 'despeckle', 'directory', 'display', 'draw', 'edge', 'emboss', 'endian', 'enhance', 'equalize', 'erase', 'fileName', 'fileSize', 'fillColor', 'fillPattern', 'fillRule', 'filterType', 'flip', 'floodFillColor', 'floodFillOpacity', 'floodFillTexture', 'flop', 'font', 'fontPointsize', 'fontTypeMetrics', 'format', 'frame', 'gamma', 'gaussianBlur', 'geometry', 'gifDisposeMethod', 'iccColorProfile', 'implode', 'interlaceType', 'iptcProfile', 'isValid', 'label', 'lineWidth', 'magick', 'magnify', 'map', 'matte', 'matteColor', 'matteFloodfill', 'meanErrorPerPixel', 'medianFilter', 'minify', 'modifyImage', 'modulate', 'modulusDepth', 'monochrome', 'montageGeometry', 'negate', 'normalize', 'normalizedMaxError', 'normalizedMeanError', 'oilPaint', 'opacity', 'opaque', 'page', 'penColor', 'penTexture', 'ping', 'pixelColor', 'process', 'profile', 'quality', 'quantize', 'quantizeColorSpace', 'quantizeColors', 'quantizeDither', 'quantizeTreeDepth', 'raise', 'read', 'readPixels', 'reduceNoise', 'registerId', 'renderingIntent', 'resolutionUnits', 'roll', 'rotate', 'rows', 'sample', 'scale', 'scene', 'segment', 'shade', 'sharpen', 'shave', 'shear', 'signature', 'size', 'solarize', 'spread', 'statistics', 'stegano', 'stereo', 'strokeAntiAlias', 'strokeColor', 'strokeDashOffset', 'strokeLineCap', 'strokeLineJoin', 'strokeMiterLimit', 'strokePattern', 'strokeWidth', 'subImage', 'subRange', 'swirl', 'syncPixels', 'textEncoding', 'texture', 'threshold', 'throwImageException', 'tileName', 'totalColors', 'transform', 'transformOrigin', 'transformReset', 'transformRotation', 'transformScale', 'transformSkewX', 'transformSkewY', 'transparent', 'trim', 'type', 'unregisterId', 'unsharpmask', 'verbose', 'view', 'wave', 'write', 'writePixels', 'x11Display', 'xResolution', 'yResolution', 'zoom']`

Answer (score 19):

From what I can tell, PythonMagick wrapps the [Magick++ library](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Documentation.html). I have been able to copy and paste C++ code using this library into python and it works as expected. Plus the names of the classes and member functions match (where as MagickWand seems to be totally different).

```
    import PythonMagick as Magick
    img = Magick.Image("testIn.jpg")
    img.quality(100) #full compression
    img.magick('PNG')
    img.write("testOut.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is still trying to find the documentation of PythonMagick, PythonMagick is exactly the same as Magick++ (API for C++). [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Documentation.html) is the Magick++ documentation. For some specific parameter, you will need to find the type then the enumeration (e.g. gravity->PythonMagick.GravityType.thegravityyouwant)

Answer (score 2):

PythonMagick isn't exactly the same as Magick++, it maps to a **subset** of Magick++. So if you start trying to use it based on the C++ documentation, you'll eventually run into something that isn't mapped.
After wasting a lot of time (in my 30 years as a developer) with inadequately-documented libraries, I've developed a rule:
**If it isn't properly documented, don't use it.**

I eventually did what I needed to do using python3-PIL. It's a pity, because ImageMagick is really nice to use from C++. But I recommend my rule. In the long run, it will save you a lot of time.