# Where can I find PythonMagick documentation?

Tags: python, imagemagick

I cant seem to find the PythonMagick (Bindings for ImageMagick) documentation anywhere. Even the download doesn't have a docs folder. Link please?

Comment: are you familiar with imagemagick documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is active anymore. - **[look here](http://sxoop.wordpress.com/2006/11/29/whither-pythonmagick/)**

Answer (score 2):

I think [Pratik Deoghare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58737/pratik-deoghare) is wrong here, the article by his link was written in 2006, but PythonMagick was active as of September 2012.

There are 3 libraries to work with ImageMagick through Python:

- [PythonMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/), an object-oriented Python interface to ImageMagick, 0.9.8 is of 19-Sep-2012
- [PythonMagickWand](https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/pythonmagickwand), an object-oriented Python interface to MagickWand based on ctypes, revision 53 is of 21-Jan-2009
- [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.2-maintenance/index.html), a ctypes-based ImageMagick binding library for Python, version 0.2.4 is of 28-May-2013

For more bindings see [ImageMagick: Application Program Interfaces](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php).

Answer (score 1):

Check out my post here for a workaround.

[Documents and examples of PythonMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740158/documents-and-examples-of-pythonmagick/5188661#5188661)

Answer (score 0):

Check out PIL : http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

IMHO, does a decent job.

Comment: Need to convert PDFs to PNGs so no PIL for me.