# Insert colorful emoji into an image(Python)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to insert emoji into an image using pillow library but the result is not what I want.

I want the emoji look exactly the same as it looks in iphone, but the result is a black and white ugly emoji.

this is my code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

back_ground_color = (255, 255, 255)
font_color = (0, 0, 0)

unicode_text = u"\U0001f618"
im = Image.new("RGB", (200, 200), back_ground_color)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("Symbola.ttf", 36)
draw.text((80, 80), unicode_text, font=unicode_font, fill=font_color)
im.show()
```

and below is the reult:

[image]

So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What you get is the pic from the [symbola.ttf](https://github.com/stv0g/unicode-emoji/blob/master/symbola/1f618.png). You may need a different source in my opinion.

Comment: @NWiogrhkt I just changed my font to [Apple Color Emoji.ttf](https://github.com/potyt/fonts/blob/master/macfonts/Apple%20Color%20Emoji/Apple%20Color%20Emoji.ttf) and now i am getting a weird error. `OSError: invalid size handle`

Comment: [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3066) is a issue about this problem with a couple of hints.

Answer (score 4):

Pillow 8.0.0 has now been released by adding support for COLR fonts.

Source:
https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/4955

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this is not yet implemented in pillow as can be seen here:
https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3346
and here :
https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/4955

Maybe you need to try a workaround like described here:
[How to render emojis as images in Python under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128951/how-to-render-emojis-as-images-in-python-under-windows/52131155#52131155)

Comment: I just used the last link you provided and everything worked except that the font he has used is Symbola.ttf which outputs a b&w emoji. I then tried to install Apple Color Emoji but windows couldn't install it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `embedded_color=True` to your `ImageDraw.Draw(image).text` so like this:

```py
ImageDraw.Draw(image).text((0, 332), "\U0001F3AC\U0001F44B\U0001F3FB\U0001F44B\U0001F3FF", fill="white", embedded_color=True, font=fnt)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Symbola is not a color emoji font, you can not show color emoji with it!

You need to try those color emoji fonts, like NotoColorEmoji, AppleColorEmoji or segoeuiemoji. The first two are bit-map color emoji font and the last one is vector color emoji font.

I have tested the three font and they work well for me:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

back_ground_color = (255, 255, 255)

unicode_text = "\U0001f602"
im = Image.new("RGB", (500, 500), back_ground_color)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

# seem only black and white, no color info
# unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype(r"E:\symbola-font\Symbola-AjYx.ttf", 30)

# bit-map based, src: https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/blob/main/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf
# unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype(r"E:\NotoColorEmoji.ttf", 109)

# bit-map based, src: https://github.com/samuelngs/apple-emoji-linux/releases
unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype(r"E:\AppleColorEmoji.ttf", 137)

# font from here: https://fontsdata.com/132714/segoeuiemoji.htm (for test only)
# svg-based, works with different font size
# unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype(r"E:\segoeuiemoji\seguiemj.ttf", 50)

draw.text((80, 80), unicode_text, font=unicode_font, embedded_color=True)
im.show()
```

Pillow version: 8.3.2

### Ref

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/4955